# Smooth movements are jerky on my laptop's integrated screen. Any software to test it out?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, video, display

I tested my new computer with multimedia and unfortunately smooth movement looks jumpy and jerky as in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTMk90HlAqM) when being played in the internal monitor. This problem doesn't only affect local video clips but also Youtube videos and moving screensavers from what I've seen.
Intel support made me test those clips on an external monitor and surprisingly the problem is [gone](https://communities.intel.com/message/384542#384542).
Now I want to test my internal monitor to see when does the problem occur (videos, games, desktop programs...).
Is there anything other than video available to test this? My idea is to use some software or animation that generates smooth movement and see how does it play on both the internal and the external monitor.
Do you have any other suggested software that may be helpful to better understand this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check out 3dMark @ http://3dmark.com/ .
Also check the visibility of the 2 UFOs (animated objects intended) here: http://www.testufo.com while varying the given options.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I noticed that the two ufos were stuttering only when f.lux screen filter was opened in the system try (even if it was disabled). I did a huge mistake leaving it open. Thankfully my problem is solved now. I have one more question: I didn't find much information about blurbasters and testufo in the internet. Is it only useful for high framerate monitors and how can it be helpful for correct monitor functioning diagnosis?

Comment: @ema93a testufo is only used to verify  framerate problems and problems like yours which deal with motion on your screen. Another tool which every windows installation has is `dxdiag` to run it open the 'Run' dialog from the start menu and type `dxdiag` then press enter.